# About compact and connected?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, connectedness

We known the open set and closed set must say in a topology space such as: $X$ be a topological space,$Y$ is subspace of $X$, for open set $A$, we must say $A$ is open in $X$ or open in $Y$.

But for connected,if $A$ is connected set, we need to say $A$ is connected in $X$ or connected in $Y$?

For compact subspace of $X$, we know $A$ is compact set iff every covering of $A$ by open set in $X$ has a finite subcollection covering $A$. It seems to need not say Compactness is relative to some space?

Comment: Correct: connectedness and compactness of a set are independent of the ambient space. That is, if $A$ is connected or compact as a space in its own right, then it is connected or compact as a subset of any space in which it is embedded, and *vice versa*.

Comment: How to understand it? I think connect and compact is  a kind of objective existence as like the Arc length of curve, but  i feel it is not obviously from the definition,it need the open set in topological space or subspace.

Comment: If I am not mistaken the projection is homeomorphism so any set wich is connect in $Y$ is connect in $X$, the same for the compact set because the topology in the ambient space$ X$ induce the same topology in$ Y$